# Obter dados da linha após clique de botão em um Repeater ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Boa noite, minha dúvida é a seguinte... Desejo fazer um "select" dos dados de uma linha do controle Repeater de acordo com o LinkButton clicado (o lápis branco de fundo azul), assim armazenando esses dados em diferentes Sessions (nome, usuario, setor, cargo, turno e ramal), para assim jogar esses dados num formulário (que é em outra página, redirecionado após apertar o LinkButton) para que os TextBoxes do formulário receba essas Sessions em formatado de String para poder serem editados. Esse é o meu objetivo, porém o que está me impedindo de prosseguir é justamente obter os dados da linha do botão clicado. Segue imagens para melhor entendimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o resultado da página, agora por exemplo, se eu clico no botão Editar (lápis) do Zeca Amaral eu queria obter o Session["nome"] = "Zeca Amaral", Session["usuario"] = "zeca.eletro", Session["setor"] = "Elétrica", e por ai vai.

Vou passar o meu código atual

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID</th>
                    <th>
                        Nome</th>
                    <th>
                        Usuário</th>
                    <th>
                        Setor</th>
                    <th>
                        Cargo</th>
                    <th>
                        Turno</th>
                    <th>
                        Ramal</th>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" class="lbl" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNome" runat="server" class="lbl" Text='<% # DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nome") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsuario" runat="server" class="lbl" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "usuario") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSetor" runat="server" class="lbl" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "setor") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCargo" runat="server" class="lbl" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"cargo") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTurno" runat="server" class="lbl" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"turno") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRamal" runat="server" class="lbl" Text='<% #DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ramal") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditar" runat="server" class="btn-sm btn-info" ToolTip="Editar" PostBackUrl="~/Exercícios/Formulario.aspx" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' OnClick="btnEditar_Click"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnExcluir" runat="server" class="btn-sm btn-danger" ToolTip="Excluir" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id") %>' OnClick="btnExcluir_Click"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Segue .cs da página

```
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexaoCASA"].ConnectionString);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    SqlDataReader dr = null;

    try
    {
        SqlCommand sqlSelect = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, nome, usuario, setor, cargo, turno, ramal FROM spc_funcionario_aprendiz", sqlconn);

        sqlconn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlSelect);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        sqlDA.Fill(dt);

        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dr != null)
        {
            dr.Close();
        }

        if (sqlconn != null)
        {
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
    }
}

protected void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["nome"] = "";
    Session["usuario"] = "";
    Session["setor"] = "";
    Session["cargo"] = "";
    Session["turno"] = "";
    Session["ramal"] = "";
}
```

No evento btnEditar quero que as Sessions recebam o respectivo resultado que quero, já explicado anteriormente. E é isso, espero que tenham entendido e que possam me ajudar, agradeço desde já! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa é a solução conforme você está fazendo:

```
protected void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Busca o item do seu repeater
    var rptItem = (RepeaterItem)((Button)sender).Parent;

    //Busca os dados do seu item
    var dataRowView = ((DataRowView)rptItem.DataItem);

    Session["nome"] = dataRowView["nome"];
    Session["usuario"] = dataRowView["usuario"];
    Session["setor"] = dataRowView["setor"];
    Session["cargo"] = dataRowView["cargo"];
    Session["turno"] = dataRowView["turno"];
    Session["ramal"] = dataRowView["ramal"];
}
```

Há ainda outra forma:

Implemente o evento `OnItemCommand` do seu `repeater` e atribua um `CommandName` no seu `LinkButton`.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditar" runat="server" CommandName="editar"/>
```

Então no seu código, você poderá buscar os dados da seguinte forma:

```
protected void repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "editar")
    {
        //Busca os dados do seu item
        var dataRowView = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem);

        Session["nome"] = dataRowView["nome"];
        Session["usuario"] = dataRowView["usuario"];
        Session["setor"] = dataRowView["setor"];
        Session["cargo"] = dataRowView["cargo"];
        Session["turno"] = dataRowView["turno"];
        Session["ramal"] = dataRowView["ramal"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado, acabei testando e deu certo! Fiz de outra maneira também usando a página do formulário. No evento do btnEditar coloquei:
`protected void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
    `{
        Session["id"] = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
        Response.Redirect("Formulario.aspx");
    }`
Após isso no .cs do formulário eu coloquei a leitura de dados e passei para os TextBoxes de edição, assim para fazer o update.. Fiz mais coisas mas resumidamente é isso.
Obrigado pela ajuda :)